# XSLT create CSV but maintain commas from XML node

Tags: excel, csv, xslt

I have an XML file that I want to create a csv file to be opened in MS Excel. The csv file uses commas as its delimiter, but one of the XML nodes has commas in it, And Excel is reading those commas as if they're supposed to be in a seperate cell. So in my example Block 1, Block 1+, Block 5, Block 5 Exportable instead of keeping this content in one cell each comma is treated as a new cell for each comma, when opened in Excel. I've tried using tab characters to delimit the csv, but that doesn't work. I've also tried encloseing the node in quotes.

How can I make the string with multiple commas to fill just one cell?

```
XML:
<dmodule>
      <title>ABC DEF</title>
      <applic id="UHK97000-10_UHK97000-12_UHK97000-15_UHK97000-17_UHK97000-18_UHK97000-20_UHK97000-21">
        <displayText>
          <simplePara>Block 1, Block 1+, Block 5, Block 5 Exportable</simplePara>
        </displayText>
     </applic>
     <tminfo>Text that should appear in the next column
     </tminfo>
</dmodule>


XSLT:
<xsl:value-of select="title"/><!-- tab char -->&#9;<xsl:value-of select="simplePara>&#9;<xsl:value-of select="tminfo"><!-- new line char -->&#10;
```

I've also tried excaping the comma character and surrounding it in double quotes, but I wasn't able to get my code to run.

```
XSLT:
    <xsl:variable name="keepCommas">
    <xsl:for-each select="simplePara">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;['simplePara,',']&quot;')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

This code didn't render any output at all.

I'm limited to XSLT version 1.0
Microsoft 365 - Excel

Comment: Well, I would create an Excel table with a cell containing commas and then save/export as CSV and look at the result and try to reproduce that with XSLT. On the other hand, Excel has its own XML format(s) so there might be more complex but also smarter ways to produce import data for Excel with XSLT than relying on CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT all you need to do is simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="dmodule">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="applic/displayText/simplePara"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="tminfo"/>
    <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What if I only want to select the simplePara into a variable, then call that variable with a value of select?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do that, but you could. Where exactly are you having trouble with it?

Comment: I created a variable for the cell that has extra commas. Your code works great! Thank you!